# Erro ao realizar consulta com cáusula GroupBy do Linq no C#

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Preciso selecionar os **Grupos** anteriormente cadastrados, trazendo dados não repetidos. Porém, um erro é retornado quando realizo a consulta na tabela **Ponto de Atendimento**, onde o campo **Grupo** no qual é aplicado o `GroupBy` contém valor nulo. Como adequar o código para que ele não retorne erro se o campo **Grupo** estiver vazio?

```cs
OrigemDados = new OrigemDados(
    pontoAtendimentoService
        .RecuperarTodos(httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User)
        .Select(pontoAtendimento => new { pontoAtendimento.Id, pontoAtendimento.Grupo })
        .GroupBy(p => p.Grupo)
        .Select(grp => grp.First())
        .ToList()
        .AsQueryable(),
    pontoAtendimento => pontoAtendimento
        .GetType()
        .GetProperty("Grupo")
        .GetValue(pontoAtendimento)
        .ToString(),
    mapeapeamento);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resposta ao problema apresentado:

Incluir uma condição para que não considere quando o campo **Grupo** contiver valor nulo.

`.Where(p => p.Grupo != null)`

```cs
OrigemDados = new OrigemDados(
    pontoAtendimentoService
        .RecuperarTodos(httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User)
        .Select(pontoAtendimento => new { pontoAtendimento.Id, pontoAtendimento.Grupo })
        .Where(p => p.Grupo != null)
        .GroupBy(p => p.Grupo)
        .Select(grp => grp.First())
        .ToList()
        .AsQueryable(),
    pontoAtendimento => pontoAtendimento
        .GetType()
        .GetProperty("Grupo")
        .GetValue(pontoAtendimento)
        .ToString(),
    mapeapeamento);
```